# Switch To A Different Function After Function Finishes

Tags: powershell-4.0

I have a script for creating and managing Active Directory users.

After a function has run, I need it to switch back to the `RBFTMenu` function.

Is there a way to do this?

**EDIT**

*Menu*

```bsh
function RBFTMenu {
    cls
    Write-Host 'User Creation

1. Create a Single User
2. Create Multiple Users

_________________________________________________

Active Directory ~ User Management

3. Password Reset
4. Disable/Enable A User Account

_________________________________________________

Exchange ~ User Management

5. Give Full Mailbox Access

q. Quit

'

    while (($RBFTSelection = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please Select An Option & Press Enter') -notin 1,2,3,4,5 ,'q') {
        Write-Warning "$RBFTSelection is not a valid option"
    }

    switch ($RBFTSelection) {
        1 { New-UserManualRBFT }
        2 { New-UserFromCSVRBFT }
        3 { PasswordResetRBFT }
        4 { DisableEnableUserRBFT }
        5 { FullAccessRBFT }
    }
}
```

*Example End Of Function*

```
Write-Host " "
Write-Host " "
echo "Press Any Key To Close"
$HOST.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown") | Out-Null
$HOST.UI.RawUI.Flushinputbuffer() 
}
```

Comment: if you call the function from the `RBFTMenu` it will return to it automatically, if not, just call the `RBFTMenu` function when the script end, anyway more explanation and examples are needed, post them.

Comment: What do you mean by calling the function? I have Multiple Functions, including RBFTMenu, and  I need it to return to RBFTMenu, when the other functions end running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the function returns something by which you can decide which action to take you could invoke it in a loop like this:

```bsh
while ($true) {
    $action = RBFTMenu
    switch ($action) {
        ...
    }
}
```

---

**Edit**

Since you handle the actions in your menu function you just need to call your function in a loop:

```bsh
while ($true) {
    RBFTMenu
}
```

You should add an `exit` branch to your `switch` statement, though:

```bsh
switch ($RBFTSelection) {
    1 { New-UserManualRBFT }
    ...
    'q' { exit }
}
```